# Asset pipeline undefined variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, asset-pipeline

I am trying to use the asset pipeline in Rails 4.1 and seem to having a few issues with variables and their scope.

Here is my applications.css.scss

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
@import 'common/mixins';

@import 'common/variables'; /* variable $content-max-width defined here */
.main { height: $content-max-width; } /* works */
@import 'common/content'; /* fails, undefined variable $content-max-width */
```

I presume I have made a mistake I just don't understand what.

Comment: This problem just popped up for me, as well. Variables and mixins that worked fine before suddenly are not precompiling. The only difference I'm seeing is that my most recent app is on Rails 4.1.1, whereas others are 4.1.0 and below. I'm starting to think it's a bug.

Comment: you requiring the complete tree and then you doing some imports? remove the require_tree

Comment: @marvwhere add it is an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the

```
*= require_tree .
```

otherwise, you load everything twice and also there is no chance to load it in the correct order. rails just load it in a "random" way and then u most of the time run into errors.